# Verb after 'never' is in what tense?

Tags: tenses

Does it need to be in base form, present tense , past tense , past participle or continual tense ? EXAMPLE: She never (*forget/ forgets/ forgot / forgotten/ forgetting ) to do her homework.

Comment: _Forgotten_ and _forgetting_ are participles and can't be used as main verbs without auxiliary verbs. That leaves out the last two. All of the first 3 are OK, but _forgets_ requires a Third Person Singular noun phrase (like _she_) as its subject, and _forget_ requires any other kind of noun phrase (first or second person, or third plural). _Forgot_, the past tense, is OK with any subject. The word _never_ has nothing to do with the verb, except that it must either go after the first auxiliary verb, or right before the main verb if there is no auxiliary (as here).

Comment: Hello, Alice. Unfortunately, this is not a question appropriate to this site.

Comment: @JohnLawler  You say:  *The word never...must either go after the first auxiliary verb, or right before the main verb if there is no auxiliary*. How about: 'I never have forgotten the look on her face when she saw me suddenly appear'? *Never* is before the auxiliary and it sounds alright to me!

Comment: @WS2: Well, the actual rule is that _never_ must go immediately before a constituent that contains its focus, like all focussed words. I didn't really want to try to explain all that here. In the sentence at issue, that consists of two positions, which I articulated. [At times I mention general rules like the roles of focus and constituent with negatives and quantifiers](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+negative+focus+constituent), but my experience here is that nobody pays attention to them; people seem to prefer inferring general rules from individual analyses instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'never' is not a verb at all. It is an Adverb of Time. It modifies the verb (forget, in this case) associating it with time. It can thus, be used in any tense.